# <React> how to modify the link color of amchart5 - <Force-Directed Tree>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amcharts, amcharts5

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DerFi.jpg)

The width of the link (line) can be modified, but the color does not change.

I've tried many things

```
series.links.template.setAll({
      strokeWidth: 2,
      strokeOpacity: 0.5,
      color: am5.color('#ffffff'),
      links: am5.color('#ffffff'),
      link: am5.color('#ffffff'),
      fill: am5.color('#ffffff'),
      strokeColor: am5.color('#ffffff'),
      background: am5.color('#ffffff'),
      backgroundColor: am5.color('#ffffff'),
      stroke: am5.color('#ffffff'),
      templateField: 'nodeSettings',
      configField: {
        fill: am5.color('#ffffff'),
        stroke: am5.color('#ffffff'),
        strokeColor: am5.color('#ffffff'),
      },
      strokeLinejoin: 'round',
    });
```

Comment: do you have a sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to change link color in amchart5

```
series.on('visible', function (visible, target) {
      if (visible) {
        target.links.each(function (link) {
          link.set('color', am5.Color.fromString('#da2b2b'));
          link.set('stroke', am5.Color.fromString('#da2b2b'));
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).